# False virus positive from my Delphi console utility

Tags: delphi, console-application, virus, delphi-xe3

A customer has reported McAfee detecting a 'Generic BackDoor.add' during the installation of my Delphi Application written using Delphi XE3. I have replicated this result by using [Virus Total](http://www.virustotal.com) which returns this virus positive on a small utility EXE file that I have written in Delphi as a console application and believe this to be the file that caused the report (not the main Application EXE).

The utility calls the service control manager (SCM) to install a '.sys' file during the [Run] phase of Innosetup. I actually deploy two versions of this utility EXE, one as a console app and the other that has the same Delphi SCM code unit but it adds a small GUI form with buttons. This latter utility does not show up as a virus positive, only the console app shows up. My app requires elevation to run using the "{$R uac_manifest.res}" inclusion. The DPR part of my utility app is shown below. (Note that this does not show the Service Control Manager calls because they are in another unit, however this other unit is used by my GUI utility version which does not trigger virus detection, hence I conclude that the problem is in my DPR - maybe?):

```
    program ArtSCM;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  UArtSysDriverInstaller;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R uac_manifest.res}
{$R *.res}

var
  sDriverName : string;


function CommandLineParamExistsWithArg(
     const ALookFor  : string;
     var   AArgument : string ) : boolean; overload;
{ Looks for the occurance of 'ALookFor' on the command line,
  of the form ALookFor=<AArgument>, where if found, AArgument returns
  the argument in upper case, AArgCaseAsIs returns the argument case as is. }
var
   I : integer;
   S : string;
begin
  Result := False;
  AArgument := '';

  For I := 1 to ParamCount do
    begin
    S := AnsiDequotedStr(ParamStr(I), '"');
    AArgument := UpperCase(S);
    Result := Pos( UpperCase(ALookFor)+'=', AArgument) = 1 ;
    If Result then
       begin
       Delete( AArgument, 1, Length(ALookFor)+1);
       Break;
       end;
    end;

  If not Result then
    AArgument := '';

end;




function PerformCommandLineAction : boolean;
var
  Installer : TArtSysDriverInstaller;

  procedure Install;
  begin
    Result := True;
    Installer := TArtSysDriverInstaller.Create( sDriverName );
    try
      Installer.InstallDriver;
    finally
      Installer.Free;
    end;
    Writeln( '  Driver installed OK.' );
  end;


  procedure Query;
  var
    S : string;
  begin
    Result := True;
    Installer := TArtSysDriverInstaller.Create( sDriverName );
    try
      If Installer.DriverIsInstalledAndRunning then
        begin
        S := Installer.DriverVersionString;
        S := Format('The driver is installed and running - Version %s.', [S] );
        end
       else
        S := 'The driver is *NOT* installed and running.';
    finally
      Installer.Free;
    end;
    Writeln( '  Status: ', S );
  end;

  procedure GetArtInfo;
  var
    S : string;
  begin
    Result := True;
    Installer := TArtSysDriverInstaller.Create( sDriverName );
    try
      If Installer.DriverIsInstalledAndRunning then
        begin
        S := Installer.ARTDriverInfoString;
        S := Format('Driver info string: %s', [S] );
        end
       else
        S := 'The driver is *NOT* installed and running.';
    finally
      Installer.Free;
    end;
    Writeln( '  Status: ', S );
  end;

  procedure Remove;
  begin
    Result := True;
    Installer := TArtSysDriverInstaller.Create( sDriverName );
    try
      Installer.RemoveDriver;
    finally
      Installer.Free;
    end;
    Writeln( '  Driver removed OK.' );
  end;



begin

  Result := False;

  try

    If not CommandLineParamExistsWithArg(
      '/DriverName',
      sDriverName )
       or (Length( sDriverName ) < 3) then
        Raise Exception.Create( 'Missing or invalid /DriverName=xxx parameter' );

    Writeln( '  Driver name: ', sDriverName );    

    If FindCmdLineSwitch(
      'QUERY' ) then
        Query
     else
    If FindCmdLineSwitch(
      'GETARTINFO' ) then
        GetArtInfo
     else
    If FindCmdLineSwitch(
      'REMOVE' ) then
        Remove
     else
    If FindCmdLineSwitch(
      'INSTALL' ) then
        Install
    else
      Raise Exception.Create( 'Missing command - QUERY, GETARTINFO, REMOVE or INSTALL required.' );

  except
    on E:Exception do
      begin
      Writeln( '  Error: ', E.Message );
      ExitCode := 1;
      end;
  end
end;


function IsRunningInDelphiIDE : boolean;
// Returns TRUE if the program is running in the IDE, FALSE otherwise.
begin
  Result := DebugHook <> 0;
end;








var
  dwVersion : DWORD;
begin
  dwVersion := GetFileVersion( ParamStr(0));

  Writeln( Format(
    'ArtDrvSC V%d.%d (c) Applied Relay Testing Ltd 2011',
    [HiWord(dwVersion), LoWord(dwVersion)] ));

  PerformCommandLineAction;

  If IsRunningInDelphiIDE then
    begin
    Writeln( 'Press a key ..' );
    Readln;
    end;
end.
```

As you see, the line "{$R uac_manifest.res}" correctly requests elevation if I run it from a command line, the manifest being:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Applied Relay Testing Ltd" version="3.1.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"/> 
  <dependency> 
    <dependentAssembly> 
    </dependentAssembly> 
  </dependency> 
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"> 
    <security> 
      <requestedPrivileges> 
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/> 
        </requestedPrivileges> 
    </security> 
  </trustInfo> 
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista --> 
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 --> 
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/> 
    </application> 
  </compatibility> 
</assembly>
```

Can anyone comment on what I should be doing to eliminate this virus detection please?

Comment: Report the false positive to the AV company, add an exception for your application on the client's machine and wait. Nothing else you can do,  since it's not a virus and not your fault.

Comment: Story: a few days ago BitDefender, my antivirus, started finding a trojan in my freshly produced Delphi exes (ie: Hit RUN in Delphi, it compiles but Access Denied when trying to run because the AV was interfering). Clearly a false-positive. I disabled the AV in the evening so I could get on with my work, after the next morning's update the problem was gone, the AV's false positive was resolved.

Comment: @Cosmin, Interesting. Just to add to the mix, I rebuilt the console app in XE3 (instead of XE2) signed it with our company code-signing certificate (although I am pretty sure it was signed before) and now it passes the virus check. Argh! As you say, its all about patterns I guess.

Comment: @opc0de Malware is never signed because it doesn't make any difference to detection. If AV vendors were to start blindly whitelisting anything that was signed, malware would suddenly all be signed!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, signing could be used by AV companies to whitelist stuff, then blacklist certificates known to be used for signing mallware. It would self-regulate: certification authorities that are too quick to provide one with a certificate would lose there trust so they'd have a proper incentive to check the identity of clients. If one finds there certificate was stolen and used to sign mallware they'd be more careful next time. But it's a chicken-egg situation: AV's don't do it because most software is not signed and software companies don't do it because it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Cosmin That will never happen. Certificates can be supplied by the most reputable company and sold to the most reputable company, and then stolen by one bad employee. Would you trust an AV product? That would simply let anything through if it was signed? I wouldn't.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I don't think there are enough bad employees with access to enough code-signing certificates to supply all the "mallware" market. It's whole different ball-game. A stolen certificate can be traced back to the originating company and then there's a change the certificate could be traced back to the "bad" employee. And that would be a serious punishable crime. I'm not saying AV companies would suddenly only rely on certificates, they should be able to detect new mallware even if it's signed, but possibly not on client's machines. And then they'd get the certificate revoked.